# Self-accepted answer vs non-accepted answers with same vote count: not ordered randomly on some browsers

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, self-answer, browsers, answer-order

**[EDIT2]**

Something is wrong with answer ordering: different versions of Chrome (under different environnments) show different behaviour.

Noticed here: [How to debug IE9 HTA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397152/how-to-debug-ie9-hta?answertab=votes#tab-top)

- WinXP(VM) and Win7, Chrome Version 33.0.1750.154 m: constant order
- Linux, Chrome Version 23.0.1271.95: random order

Might extends to other browsers?

**[EDIT1]**

In the end it looks like a browser specific issue, in the very particular case of:

- a self-accepted answer with N votes,
- other non-accepted answers which with N votes too,
- sorting answers by vote,
- the browser is an old version Chrome, Firefox (which version?), maybe others too.

In this case, the order of the answers with N votes varies randomly at each refresh, including the accepted one. This doesn't happen on more recent versions of Chrome, accepted answer is always first and the order remains the same between refreshes.

**[ORIGINAL]**

I understand the choice of using random for ordering equally voted answers: a simple way of giving the same visibility without the hassle of taking rep or time into account, etc.

However I had the case where I needed to refer to an accepted answer which had the same number of votes than other, less acurate answers, and was surprised to have to search it each time I reopened the page (there can be many answers with 1 vote).

See this question for example: [How to debug IE9 HTA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397152/how-to-debug-ie9-hta?answertab=votes#tab-top), where the accepted answer is not ordered at the beginning.

Do accepted answers deserve more visibility than others when votes are equal?

Comment: Are you sure? I thought accepted answers were always the first after the question?

Comment: Can you link us to the question where this is occurring for you?

Comment: @codeMagic: AFAIK, accepted answers are ordered by votes when you accept your own answer.

Comment: @Flimzy that may be but there was nothing in the question suggesting that it was a self-answer

Comment: @codeMagic: No, but that makes your "always" supposition inaccurate :)

Comment: @Flimzy touche!

Comment: @codeMagic Yep I refreshed the page several times when I saw that

Comment: But was it an answer posted by the OP or a different user. Also, @TarynEast suggested, can you link to it?

Comment: @TarynEast I'm not at work anymore, from memory it was [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397152/how-to-debug-ie9-hta?answertab=votes#tab-top) but I cannot seem to reproduce this behavior. Could it be browser dependent?

Comment: I'm confused. Are you asking if accepted answers deserve more visibility period, or if they deserve more visibility if they have the same amount of votes as non-accepted answers?

Comment: I reproduced the issue with that question. In this browser I have deliberately chosen sorting by "votes" for answers... so it could be that.

Comment: @TarynEast Normally, the accepted answer will always be on top, regardless of how many votes it has. The only exception is when it's a self-answered question. In this case, the answer will be sorted as usual.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ Only when they have the same amount of votes as non-accepted answers (and apparently in the particular case of self-answered questions only, thanks for mentionning this)

Comment: @TarynEast That's strange, I'm ordering by votes here and the accepted answer always appear before the other non-accepted answers with same score (0 in this case). Browser issue?

Comment: @zeiky - could be. I'm currently using Firefox. If you look at the link above - it includes "?answertab=votes#tab-top" - if I remove that - the sorting changes but still not accepted-answer first. Note: it does order the accepted answer after the answer with 4 votes

Comment: Note: this is a self-accepted answer.

Comment: @TarynEast On my home PC with recent Chrome, accepted answer is always first event without the "?answertab..." part. At work with older Chrome, order varies. Should I add the bug tag and reformulate my question?

Comment: @zeiky it isn't browser specific.  The sort order is random when 2 or more questions have the same number of votes.  I have the latest non-beta version of Chrome and I am seeing your answer in random locations.  You should check your sort order is set to "votes" because that's the only thing that should impact what you are seeing.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I also use vote ordering and the order is constant on home PC with Chrome version 33.0.1750.154 m.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes as this started as a discussion, then turned out to possibly reveal a bug; pretty sure I'm not the only one having constant order on the linked question. Probably not a duplicate neither.

Comment: @zeiky I am running the same version of Chrome and I can't replicate this "bug".  I see your answer in different locations as it supposed to be happening.  I imagine the downvotes might be other users saying this is not a bug either.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I just tried with another Chrome browser version 33.0.1750.154 m in a VirtualBox and order is constant. Not sure why we don't observe the same behaviour.

Comment: This definitely shouldn't be closed as dupe of that generic question.

Answer (score 7):

Normally accepted answers are shown on top. If the question asker accepts his own answer, this doesn't apply. Such an answer doesn't get pushed to the top. It is sorted just the same way as if it wouldn't be accepted, which is randomly among those answers with the same score.

This is not a bug but [by design](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/). If it really behaves differently in chrome, then *that* would be a bug.

Comment: Obligatory: http://dilbert.com/strips/comic/2001-10-25/

Comment: I'm using Chrome "Version 33.0.1750.154 m" here and answer order is constant indeed. @AnnaLear, I tried many refreshes, maybe the problem lies [here instead](http://xkcd.com/221/)